# I'm trying to create a Mandelbulb in Blender 3.3.1 using the scripter. Zero errors but nothing happens when I run the code

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, error, mathematics

Below is my current code. I get no errors, but when I run the code nothing happens. I'm not even sure everything is right, or when it works will it work how I want. Any feedback or suggestions are helpful. Overall the end result should be a nice looking 3D Mandelbulb with decently high detail, hundreds of thousands of faces are expected if not more.

Code:

````
import bpy
import numpy as np
import math

def mandelbulb(x, y, z, iterations):
    c = x + y*1j + z*1j
    z = c
    r = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        r2 = x*x + y*y + z*z
        if r2 > 2:
            return i/iterations
        theta = math.atan2(math.sqrt(x*x + y*y), z)
        phi = math.atan2(y, x)
        r = r2**(1/8)
        x = r * math.sin(theta/8) * math.cos(phi/8) + c.real
        y = r * math.sin(theta/8) * math.sin(phi/8) + c.imag
        z = r * math.cos(theta/8)
    return 0

def generate_mesh(size, iterations):
    vertices = []
    faces = []
    for x in np.linspace(-2, 2, size):
        for y in np.linspace(-2, 2, size):
            for z in np.linspace(-2, 2, size):
                value = mandelbulb(x, y, z, iterations)
                if value > 0:
                    vertices.append((x, y, z))
    return vertices, faces

def create_mesh_object(vertices, faces, name):
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
    mesh.from_pydata(vertices, [], faces)
    mesh.update()
    object = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)

def execute(size, iterations):
    vertices, faces = generate_mesh(size, iterations)
    create_mesh_object(vertices, faces, "Mandelbulb")

class MandelbulbOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.mandelbulb_operator"
    bl_label = "Mandelbulb Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    size = bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Size",
        default=32,
        min=1,
        max=256,
        step=1,
        precision=0
    )
    iterations = bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Iterations",
        default=64,
        min=1,
        max=512,
        step=1,
        precision=0
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        execute(self.size, self.iterations)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Create a 3D Mandelbulb")
        layout.prop(self, "size")
        layout.prop(self, "iterations")
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MandelbulbOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MandelbulbOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

```
````

Comment: Just a hint: The script registers an operator. You need to run the operator so that the script actually does something. Run the script, then press F3, and search for "Mandelbulb Operator". The execute() method will then run. But there is a problem with the Size property and there will be an error :-( Need to have a closer look to solve it.

Comment: @Blunder I just tried the F3 and it seems like it can't find "Mandelbulb Operator" or any similar searches like "MandelbulbOperator"

Comment: Replace `=` with `:` in the operator properties definition (not those beiginng with `bl_` + `precision` is an invalid argument for IntProperty, remove it in both `size` and `iterations`

Answer (score 1):

There are two little mistakes in your script as Gorgious wrote in the comments:

1. the operator properties "size" and "iterations" must be defined by ":" not by a "="
2. [bpy.props.IntProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.IntProperty) has no *precision* parameter.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
import math

def mandelbulb(x, y, z, iterations):
    c = x + y*1j + z*1j
    z = c
    r = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        r2 = x*x + y*y + z*z
        if r2 > 2:
            return i/iterations
        theta = math.atan2(math.sqrt(x*x + y*y), z)
        phi = math.atan2(y, x)
        r = r2**(1/8)
        x = r * math.sin(theta/8) * math.cos(phi/8) + c.real
        y = r * math.sin(theta/8) * math.sin(phi/8) + c.imag
        z = r * math.cos(theta/8)
    return 0

def generate_mesh(size, iterations):
    vertices = []
    faces = []
    for x in np.linspace(-2, 2, size):
        for y in np.linspace(-2, 2, size):
            for z in np.linspace(-2, 2, size):
                value = mandelbulb(x, y, z, iterations)
                if value > 0:
                    vertices.append((x, y, z))
    return vertices, faces

def create_mesh_object(vertices, faces, name):
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
    mesh.from_pydata(vertices, [], faces)
    mesh.update()
    object = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)

def execute(size, iterations):
    vertices, faces = generate_mesh(size, iterations)
    create_mesh_object(vertices, faces, "Mandelbulb")

class MandelbulbOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.mandelbulb_operator"
    bl_label = "Mandelbulb Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    size: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Size",
        default=32,
        min=1,
        max=256,
        step=1
    )
    iterations: bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Iterations",
        default=64,
        min=1,
        max=512,
        step=1
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        execute(self.size, self.iterations)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Create a 3D Mandelbulb")
        layout.prop(self, "size")
        layout.prop(self, "iterations")
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MandelbulbOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MandelbulbOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

After you run the script, no error should be displayed in the *System Console* window and nothing will happen because you only have registered the operator *Mandelbulb Operator*.

Use the main menu *Edit > Menu Search...* <kbd>F3</kbd> or *Edit > Operator Search...* to find your operator. Both should work.

[image: search operator]

Menu search:
[image: menu search]

Operator search:
[image: operator search]

Select it and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute it.

With the *Adjust Last Operator* popup at the bottom left of the screen you can change the settings *Size* and *Iterations* of your *Mandelbulb Operator*.

[image: screenshot of the Mandelbulb]

If for some reason you cannot see the popup make sure the option *View > [X] Adjust Last Operation* is ticked in the viewport's menu, or press <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring it back.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of response I was looking for, thank you. It now runs without errors and i'm able to repeat your result. The problem now is of course the result looks nothing like the true Mandelbulb I'm going for. It's possible what appears is a certain stage of Mandelbulb, but it's not as detailed or cool as I was hoping. Maybe a miscalculation. I'd love to hear if you caught anything or have any suggestions for how to continue.

P.S. The "Iterations" operation that you can change doesn't seem to actually do anything.

By googling "Mandelbulb" you can see the desired result.

Comment: Yes, it looks a bit poor. Have you tried Geometry Nodes instead of Python? There is a [nice tutorial](https://youtu.be/xuLIJ-FNkSI). And in the YT comments, there is an (improved version)[https://youtu.be/qir9LcmYywg] including a [blend file](https://mega.nz/file/M0IkXLAC#2Tq5phTKwXeMopwUEGSoAdvTi4AZJy6siJyFvPCIgBE) (link in one of the YT comment). I recommend decreasing the render resolution in the GN modifier because the value of 1024 requires up to 20 GB RAM. Also, decrease the 200% upscale in the render output settings for the first test and check the missing HDRI in the world settings.

Comment: Here is an example of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU7eS.jpg